# Resize partition using Gparted without losing data

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I have a HDD capacity of 1.32 TB. I have more space left unused in my `/` partition. I want to extend `/home` by shrinking `/` without losing any data.

[image]

Comment: I never had any data loss by resizing my partitions, but there is no guarantee at all. You should ALWAYS make a backup before doing this.

Answer (score 4):

The comments say it all. Your answer is, when it comes to resizing partitions, there is no guarantee that you will not lose data. Tools like Gparted are going to do their best to prevent data loss, but nothing is 100% guaranteed.

When you use Gparted to resize (it's actually going to use other command-line tools) it will do it's best to move all of the data out of the space being reclaimed before actually shrinking the partition.

Kev Inski is right, you should [back everything up](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging) *first*. Then, and only then, should you attempt to resize the partition. If shrinking happens to cause a loss of data, it's not really lost because you backed it up first!